# Print load time per file when start a Rails 2 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

How can I print for each file how long is it taking.

I am thinking about monkey patching `load` or some load method in Rails, but I don't know a lot about Rails 2 inner things.

I would expect this kind of output:

```
config/environment.rb ---> 60 s
config/development.rb ---> 30 s
config/initializers/some.rb ---> 20 s
```

Any starting point is really appreciated.

## Update

I am measuring time with:

```
from = Time.now; p from.to_s + '----- env.rb'
to = Time.now - from; p "env.rb ---" + to.to_s
```

Changing `env.rb` to `boot.rb` in boot.rb file, these are my results:

```
"Thu Feb 13 18:54:17 +0000 2014----- boot.rb"
"boot.rb ---0.001493"
"boot.rb ---0.941835"
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.18)
"Thu Feb 13 18:54:19 +0000 2014----- env.rb"
"env.rb ---0.001378"
"Thu Feb 13 18:54:19 +0000 2014----- boot.rb"
"boot.rb ---0.001712"
"boot.rb ---0.02536"
"env.rb ---67.272745"
"env.rb ---70.847089"
```

I am not sure why I am getting that config/boot is being called twice. From what I see most of the time is spent in environment.rb, but I removed code and time remains the same, so it should be related with other thing.

This other thing is not bundling gems, since I have:

```
from = Time.now; p from.to_s + '----- env.rb'
# Be sure to restart your web server when you modify this file.
#
#
require 'rubygems'
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup


to = Time.now - from; p "env.rb ---" + to.to_s
```

And this is printing:

```
"env.rb ---0.001378"
```

Comment: use a ruby profiler like http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/

Comment: thanks, these are my results https://gist.github.com/juanpastas/78772b34d299fd20b474. I am not sure how to improve things from there though.

Comment: I used `ruby /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/ruby-prof-0.13.1/bin/ruby-prof config/environment.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that most of the time was spent in loading files, I started a new Rails 2.3 project with part of the models of the bigger app, and time reduced from more than a minute to about 5 seconds.